# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Book__c>

Tags: apex, soql

```
list<Book__c> b = [select id ,account__c,Account1__c from Book__c ];
system.debug(b);

list<account> acc = new list<account>([select id,name from account where name in :b.account__c]);
system.debug(acc);
```

> Line: 4, Column: 83
>   Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Comment: account__C contain account name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `b` is a list of objects. This would compile:

```
where name in :b[0].account__c
```

but is probably not what you want as it is only then looking at the first item.

Perhaps you want something like this is what you need:

```
// Get the set of accounts first
Set<String> accounts = new Set<String>();
for (Book__c b : [select account__c from Book__c where account__c != null]) {
    accounts.add(b.account__c);
}

list<account> acc = [select id,name from account where name in :accounts];
system.debug(acc);
```

If `Book__c.Account__c` is an Id, you should be matching the Id field in your second query.

Comment: this code work for me.. Book__c.Account__c is not id  it is name of account.

Comment: can you guide me more.. now I have taken lookup field of account on book__c now what i want whatever name in account__c that account  should append to that lookup field how shall i do that.. i written code which now work for me see below

Answer (score 3):

`IN` used to compare any field with `List` of available values. From the error message it is quite clear that `b.account__c` is not of type `list`.
Refer below example:

```
List<String> accountNames = new List<String>();
accountNames.add('Account1');
accountNames.add('Account2');

list<account> acc = new list<account>([select id,name from account where name in :accountNames]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce can give some pretty unhelpful errors at time. This one isn't the clearest, but if you pause for a moment and take a good look at it, it starts to make sense.

Besides the line number, this is the most important part of the error:

> must be a concrete SObject: List

So somewhere, on that line, Salesforce is expecting an `SObject`, but you're giving Salesforce a `List`.

We know it's on line 4. A SOQL query returns a `List`, and you're storing the result in a `List`, so there's no problem there (you actually don't need to use the `List` constructor here, or do any casting for that matter, but that's beside the point).

The only other place on line 4 that can be causing your error is this:

```
where name in :b.account__c
```

If we take a look at the lines above, `b` is defined as a `List<Book__c>`. This fits the error that you're getting. `b` is a `List`, but using dot notation to reference a field is something that needs to be done on an `SObject`.

Your list stored in `b` does contain `Book__c` records (`Book__c` is also an `SObject`), so to be able to access the `Account__c` field, you need access to one of the actual records in your list (for which you'd use `[<some integer>]` or `.get(<some integer>)`).

At the very least (and I do emphasize that this is the *very least* you could do), to make this work, you'd do the following

```
// I've omitted the rest of the query for brevity
// Notice how we use square brackets before trying to reference the field
// Apex is 0-indexed, meaning the first item in the array is at index 0 (instead of 1)
where name in :b[0].account__c];
```

Keith C's answer goes over better practices for accomplishing what you're looking to do.

Comment: yes it  work properly but it work for only particular index record.

Answer (score 0):

```
list<Book__c> b = [select id,name,account__c,Account1__c from Book__c ];
system.debug(b);

list<string> s = new list<string>();
Map<Id,account> newmap = new Map<Id,account>();    

for(book__c b1 : b){
    s.add(b1.account__c);
}
system.debug(s);

list<account> acc =[select id,name from account where name IN :s];

for(account a : acc){
    newmap.put(a.id,a);

}

system.debug(newmap);

for(account a1 : acc){
       for(book__c b1 : b){ 
               if(b1.Account1__c != null){}
                    if(b1.account__c == a1.name){

                        b1.Account1__c = a1.id;
                    }
               }
        }   
}
update b; 
system.debug(b);
```

how to solve it by using map..

Comment: This should be a new question not an answer. In the question give the type of the fields `account___c` and `Account1__c` and explain what you want to happen and what is happening. The normal way to relate two objects is using the `Id` value; if you also want a separate name field you can use a formula for that, but most Salesforce user interface will automatically present the name in place of the Id value so a separate name field isn't needed.

Comment: account___c is text field which contains account name... I have exitsing data now I want to take lookup field  Account1__c  on book__c and fill this by account whos name in account__C... so by above program it solve but As I am new in apex i not able to solve it using map

Comment: if you want more information let me know

Answer (score -3):

Where Condition Should be Return Name But It is Compared By `Ids`. You Should be Compare with Id's. Like

```
[select id,name from Account where id : b.account__c];
```

Comment: Does not address the issue. Will throw same error

Comment: account__C is text field which contains account name. and now i am taking lookup field of account on book__C. now i want who name in account__c field that account should reflect in lookup field